# Conditional formatting formula to highlight max goods's price and volume

Tags: excel

I have a question about use conditional formula to format highlight some     cells in excel.
   This is my data and I get the highlight with my hands difficult:

[image]

What I want to do is:get every goods(like Goods A for all months there's have a max price and a max volume) max price and max volume,highlight them.
   I get the highlight with click every Goods A's Price then use conditional formula get the max one,then click every Goods A's volume, use conditional formula get the max one.Then Format brush Goods A for Goods B,for Goods C...
   I asked google,and get a conditional formula format like this:
Code Is here:

```
=AND(MAX($B3:$W3)=B3,MOD(COLUMN(),2)=1)

=AND(MAX($C3:$W3)=C3,MOD(COLUMN(),2)=0)
```

But if I use this conditional formula format,I get result like this:

[image]

That's not what I want,but what's wrong with my format?

How should I do to get the right format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mark the maximum price, you need to match each cell against the maximum of all the prices. This works because all of the prices are numerically larger than the volumes. However, when you want to match against the highest volume, each volume is being compared to the maximum price again. You need to peel out the maximum volume.

First delete the old rule so that they will not interfere then select B3:W17 and add these two new formula based CF rules.

```
 'CF rule formula for maximum price
=AND(B3=MAX(INDEX($B3:$W3*MOD(COLUMN($A:$V), 2),,)), MOD(COLUMN(A:A), 2), B3<>"")
 'CF rule formula for maximum volume
=AND(B3=MAX(INDEX($B3:$W3*MOD(COLUMN($B:$W), 2),,)), MOD(COLUMN(B:B), 2), B3<>"")
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to see, but guessing how about these formulae

=MAX(IF(MOD(COLUMN($B3:$W3),2)=0,$B3:$W3,-1))=B3
=MAX(IF(MOD(COLUMN($B3:$W3),2)=1,$B3:$W3,-1))=B3

Comment: Four spaces in front of each formula will convert it to a code block. Alternately, select both rows and tap Ctrl+K.

Comment: Thank you! your second formulae =MAX(IF(MOD(COLUMN($B3:$W3),2)=1,$B3:$W3,-1))=B3 is great! but the first formulae =MAX(IF(MOD(COLUMN($B3:$W3),2)=0,$B3:$W3,-1))=B3 is wrong,can you fix it?Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You format your cell if:

- its value is the maximum value in its row AND
- the column index mod 2 is 0 or 1.

This means, that e.g. the volume cell will not be formatted if any value in a price cell is bigger, because the first part of the formula will never become true for the volume cell (you check across the whole row, not just across all volume cells).

Instead of getting the max value across the whole range, you should get your max value only for the cells you actually want to compare (like `MAX(B3;D3;F3;...)`).

Comment: Thanks very much for answer my question! But I still have a question,can you please give a series complete formula? My bee I don't just understand your point, I tried just time use =MAX(B3:D3:F3:H3:J3:L3:N3:P3:R3:T3:V3)=B2 or just like this,but it's wrong...

Comment: @Walker.li separate the cell definition with commas (`,`), not with colons (`:`) - `MAX(B3,D3,F3,H3,J3,L3,N3,P3,R3,T3,V3)=B3`

Comment: In a CF rule that governs multiple columns, that should be `=MAX($B3, $D3, $F3, ...) = B3`.

Comment: Thank you! It works,but unfortunately ,also wrong......it highlight a lot of cells......